# How To Compare 2 Strings In A Word Document With Special Character(EX : Dáceres-Nartínez)?

Tags: c#

I need to compare two strings in a word document i work it out for alphabetic and numeric values but it is not able to compare a string which contains some special characters like (Máceres-Cartínez) Here a and i is occur with special character so it is not compare.

My code is given below.
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(this.textBox1.Text);
                string strValue = sr.ReadToEnd();
                string[] strSpliter =new string[1];
                strSpliter[0] = "References";
                string[] strSplitValue = strValue.Split(strSpliter, StringSplitOptions.None);
                String[] strParaValue = strSplitValue[1].Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                FileStream fst = new FileStream(@"E:\TrueText.txt",FileMode.Append);
                StreamWriter swt = new StreamWriter(fst);
                FileStream fsf = new FileStream(@"E:\FalseText.txt", FileMode.Append);
                StreamWriter swf = new StreamWriter(fsf);

```
            swt.WriteLine("Startred on :" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd/hh/mm/ss") + "\n");
            swf.WriteLine("Startred on :" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd/hh/mm/ss") + "\n");

            foreach (string strPara in strParaValue)
            {
                string[] strAuthorsPart = strPara.Split('.');
                string[] strAuthorslist = strAuthorsPart[0].Split(',');
                string[] strAuthor = strAuthorslist[0].Split(' ');
                if (strSplitValue[0].Contains(strAuthor[0].Trim()))
                {
                    swt.WriteLine(strAuthor[0] + "\t");
                }
                else
                {

                    swf.WriteLine(strAuthor[0] + "\t");
                }
```

Did any one guide me how to resolve this?

Thanks
Deego

Answer (score 0):

I cant see you code.. Maybe this can help you:

```
bool result = Regex.IsMatch("\\bthe\\b", text);

(using System.Text.RegularExpressons.)
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(this.textBox1.Text);
            string strValue = sr.ReadToEnd();
            string[] strSpliter =new string[1];
            strSpliter[0] = "References";
            string[] strSplitValue = strValue.Split(strSpliter, StringSplitOptions.None);
            String[] strParaValue = strSplitValue[1].Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            FileStream fst = new FileStream(@"E:\TrueText.txt",FileMode.Append);
            StreamWriter swt = new StreamWriter(fst);
            FileStream fsf = new FileStream(@"E:\FalseText.txt", FileMode.Append);
            StreamWriter swf = new StreamWriter(fsf);

            swt.WriteLine("Startred on :" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd/hh/mm/ss") + "\n");
            swf.WriteLine("Startred on :" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd/hh/mm/ss") + "\n");

            foreach (string strPara in strParaValue)
            {
                string[] strAuthorsPart = strPara.Split('.');
                string[] strAuthorslist = strAuthorsPart[0].Split(',');
                string[] strAuthor = strAuthorslist[0].Split(' ');
                if (strSplitValue[0].Contains(strAuthor[0].Trim()))
                {
                    swt.WriteLine(strAuthor[0] + "\t");
                }
                else
                {

                    swf.WriteLine(strAuthor[0] + "\t");
                }
```

This is my code

Comment: This is my code. I wrote like splitting the document into two strings and compare the second string with first one for that it compile clearly but it is not compile while the document using Special characters (á-í)

Answer (score 0):

[Custom case mappings.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xk2wykcz.aspx)